# Can't understand this snippet with eval and call

Tags: javascript, vbscript, jscript

I found a demo that mixes VBScript and JScript at these two links [**here**](https://web.archive.org/web/20150810213142/http://with-love-from-siberia.blogspot.co.uk/2009/12/msgbox-inputbox-in-jscript.html), and it mentions the full code here on [**code.google.com**](https://code.google.com/p/jsxt/source/browse/trunk/js/win32/VBScript.js)

Here is the code.

I don't understand the code, and that's ok. I'd like to try it out and see the results I can get from it or what similar things I can write, and then I can study it. It runs without error.

(This isn't the snippet I refer to in my title, this is the background to the snippet. The snippet follows this)

```
//
// JavaScript unit
// Wrapper for VBScript features in JScript
//
// Copyright (c) 2009 by Ildar Shaimordanov
//
// VERY IMPORTANT!
// InputBox/MsgBox/vbXXX and their descriptions are parts of the CHM-file named as 
// "Windows Script Technologies " and all of them are properties of Microsoft 
// accordingly their copyright as below:
//
// Copyright (c) 2001 Microsoft Corporation. 
// Build: Topic Version 5.6.9309.1546 
//


var vb = {};


/**
 * The helper method creates VBScript functions to be available in JScript.
 *
 * @param       String  The name of VBScript function. 
 * @return      Function
 */
vb.Function = function(func)
{
        return function()
        {
                return vb.Function.eval.call(this, func, arguments);
        };
};

(function()
{

var vbe;

function VBEngine()
{
        if ( vbe ) {
                return;
        }

        vbe = new ActiveXObject('ScriptControl');
        vbe.Language = 'VBScript';
        vbe.AllowUI = true;
};

/**
 * The helper method runs VBScript functions to be available in JScript.
 *
 * @param       String  The name of VBScript function. 
 * @param       Array   The list of arguments for a VBScript function.
 * @return      Function
 */
vb.Function.eval = function(func)
{
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments[1]);
        for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
                if ( typeof args[i] != 'string' ) {
                        continue;
                }
                args[i] = args[i].replace(/["\n\r]/g, function($0)
                {
                        return '" + Chr(' + $0.charCodeAt($0) + ') + "';
                });
                args[i] = '"' + args[i] + '"';
        }

        VBEngine();

        return vbe.eval(func + '(' + args.join(', ') + ')');
};

})();

/**
 * vb.Function.declare()
 *
 * @description
 * Allows to declare custom VBScript functions. 
 * Returns the reference to the htmlfile document. 
 * All declarations are in the namespace of this document. 
 *
 * @example
 * // declare the generator of integer number from L to U
 * var vbs = vb.Function.declare([
 *     'Randomize', 
 *     'Function Random(L, U)', 
 *     '    Random = Int((U - L + 1) * Rnd + L)', 
 *     'End Function']);
 * 
 * // The bones generator
 * var n = vbs.Random(1, 6);
 *
 * @param       Array|String    VBScript declaratiom
 * @return      HTMLDocument
 * @access      static
 */
vb.Function.declare = function()
{
        // Initialize the declarator of VBScript items
        vb.Function.declarator = (new ActiveXObject('htmlfile')).parentWindow;

        // Redeclare the method
        vb.Function.declare = function()
        {
                var declarator = vb.Function.declarator;

                if ( ! arguments.length ) {
                        return declarator;
                }

                var args = arguments;
                if ( args[0] && args[0].constructor == Array ) {
                        args = args[0];
                }
                var func = Array.prototype.slice.call(args).join('\n');

                var document = declarator.document;
                document.write('\x3Cscript language="VBScript"\x3E' + func + '\x3C/script\x3E');

                return declarator;
        };

        // Call new method
        return vb.Function.declare.apply(null, arguments);
};


/**
 * Displays a prompt in a dialog box, waits for the user to input 
 * text or click a button, and returns the contents of the text box. 
 *
 * InputBox(prompt[, title][, default][, xpos][, ypos][, helpfile, context])
 *
 * prompt 
 * String expression displayed as the message in the dialog box. 
 * The maximum length of prompt is approximately 1024 characters, 
 * depending on the width of the characters used. If prompt 
 * consists of more than one line, you can separate the lines using 
 * a carriage return character (Chr(13)), a linefeed character 
 * (Chr(10)), or carriage return-linefeed character combination 
 * (Chr(13) & Chr(10)) between each line. 
 *
 * title 
 * String expression displayed in the title bar of the dialog box. 
 * If you omit title, the application name is placed in the title 
 * bar. 
 *
 * default 
 * String expression displayed in the text box as the default 
 * response if no other input is provided. If you omit default, 
 * the text box is displayed empty. 
 *
 * xpos 
 * Numeric expression that specifies, in twips, the horizontal 
 * distance of the left edge of the dialog box from the left edge 
 * of the screen. If xpos is omitted, the dialog box is 
 * horizontally centered. 
 *
 * ypos 
 * Numeric expression that specifies, in twips, the vertical 
 * distance of the upper edge of the dialog box from the top of the 
 * screen. If ypos is omitted, the dialog box is vertically 
 * positioned approximately one-third of the way down the screen. 
 *
 * helpfile 
 * String expression that identifies the Help file to use to 
 * provide context-sensitive Help for the dialog box. If helpfile is 
 * provided, context must also be provided. 
 *
 * context 
 * Numeric expression that identifies the Help context number 
 * assigned by the Help author to the appropriate Help topic. 
 * If context is provided, helpfile must also be provided. 
 *
 * Remarks
 * When both helpfile and context are supplied, a Help button is 
 * automatically added to the dialog box.
 * If the user clicks OK or presses ENTER, the InputBox function 
 * returns whatever is in the text box. If the user clicks Cancel, 
 * the function returns a zero-length string ("").
 */
var InputBox = vb.Function('InputBox');


/**
 * Displays a message in a dialog box, waits for the user to click 
 * a button, and returns a value indicating which button the user 
 * clicked.
 *
 * MsgBox(prompt[, buttons][, title][, helpfile, context])
 *
 * prompt
 * String expression displayed as the message in the dialog box. 
 * The maximum length of prompt is approximately 1024 characters, 
 * depending on the width of the characters used. If prompt consists 
 * of more than one line, you can separate the lines using a 
 * carriage return character (Chr(13)), a linefeed character 
 * (Chr(10)), or carriage return-linefeed character combination 
 * (Chr(13) & Chr(10)) between each line. 
 *
 * buttons
 * Numeric expression that is the sum of values specifying the 
 * number and type of buttons to display, the icon style to use, 
 * the identity of the default button, and the modality of the 
 * message box. See vb.XXX constants for values. If omitted, 
 * the default value for buttons is 0. 
 *
 * title
 * String expression displayed in the title bar of the dialog box. 
 * If you omit title, the application name is placed in the 
 * title bar. 
 *
 * helpfile
 * String expression that identifies the Help file to use to 
 * provide context-sensitive Help for the dialog box. If helpfile 
 * is provided, context must also be provided. Not available on 
 * 16-bit platforms. 
 *
 * context
 * Numeric expression that identifies the Help context number 
 * assigned by the Help author to the appropriate Help topic. 
 * If context is provided, helpfile must also be provided. 
 * Not available on 16-bit platforms. 
 *
 * Remarks
 * See vb.XXX constants for identify a returned value. 
 * When both helpfile and context are provided, the user can 
 * press F1 to view the Help topic corresponding to the context. 
 * If the dialog box displays a Cancel button, pressing the ESC key 
 * has the same effect as clicking Cancel. If the dialog box 
 * contains a Help button, context-sensitive Help is provided for 
 * the dialog box. However, no value is returned until one of the 
 * other buttons is clicked.
 * When the MsgBox function is used with Microsoft Internet Explorer, 
 * the title of any dialog presented always contains "VBScript:" to 
 * differentiate it from standard system dialogs. 
 */
var MsgBox = vb.Function('MsgBox');


/**
 * The following constants are used with the MsgBox function to 
 * identify what buttons and icons appear on a message box and which 
 * button is the default. In addition, the modality of the MsgBox 
 * can be specified. Since these constants are built into VBScript, 
 * you don't have to define them before using them. Use them 
 * anywhere in your code to represent the values shown for each. 
 */
vb.OKOnly           =    0; // Display OK button only. 
vb.OKCancel         =    1; // Display OK and Cancel buttons. 
vb.AbortRetryIgnore =    2; // Display Abort, Retry, and Ignore buttons. 
vb.YesNoCancel      =    3; // Display Yes, No, and Cancel buttons. 
vb.YesNo            =    4; // Display Yes and No buttons. 
vb.RetryCancel      =    5; // Display Retry and Cancel buttons. 
vb.Critical         =   16; // Display Critical Message icon.  
vb.Question         =   32; // Display Warning Query icon. 
vb.Exclamation      =   48; // Display Warning Message icon. 
vb.Information      =   64; // Display Information Message icon. 
vb.DefaultButton1   =    0; // First button is default. 
vb.DefaultButton2   =  256; // Second button is default. 
vb.DefaultButton3   =  512; // Third button is default. 
vb.DefaultButton4   =  768; // Fourth button is default. 
vb.ApplicationModal =    0; // Application modal; the user must respond to the message box before continuing work in the current application. 
vb.SystemModal      = 4096; // System modal; all applications are suspended until the user responds to the message box. 


/**
 * The following constants are used with the MsgBox function to 
 * identify which button a user has selected. These constants are 
 * only available when your project has an explicit reference to 
 * the appropriate type library containing these constant 
 * definitions. For VBScript, you must explicitly declare 
 * these constants in your code. 
 */
vb.OK     = 1; // OK 
vb.Cancel = 2; // Cancel 
vb.Abort  = 3; // Abort 
vb.Retry  = 4; // Retry 
vb.Ignore = 5; // Ignore 
vb.Yes    = 6; // Yes 
vb.No     = 7; // No
```

So that's some background to the following snippet I am trying out.

So I tried to write the following little snippet and it compiled/interpreted fine. no error

```
a={};
a.abc = function(func)
{
        return function()
        {
                return a.abc.eval.call(this, func, arguments);
        };
};

a.abc("asdf");
```

It runs without error.

I understand a is being defined there as an object, and we're adding a function to it, and the function returns a function. Though what that function does, I'm not sure.

In trying to understand it... it looks like eval is a function, because after it, call is invoked, and that couldn't be done if eval were a property.

(And I know I can do eval on its own, e.g. from the console eval("5+6"); so eval there is a function)

But if I put that snippet in the console (so as to create the a object and its abc function), and then I do

typeof a.abc.eval  <-- undefined

a.abc.eval() <-- "Uncaught TypeError: a.abc.eval is not a function"

I don't see why it'd say undefined and that a.abc.eval isn't a function when I have code that says "a.abc.eval.call"

Comment: `eval` is another function of the `vb` object (technically, `vb` is being used as a _namespace_ here). See further down the code example you posted: `vb.Function.eval = function(func)`.

Comment: @Bond  Can you refer your explanation to my snippet rather than the main code 'cos the main code is rather large and was just background to the snippet.  In my snippet I did a.abc.eval   are you saying that 'a' is a namespace? It looks to me like `a` is an object and abc is the name of a function of that object.

Comment: Your snippet relies on an `eval` function that's defined in the original but not included in yours.

Comment: @Bond ok, I see, but the function compiles, and i've just added a line to the snippet that runs the function, and it still compiles/interprets without error

Comment: Change `eval` to anything else and you'll see that it still runs without error. JavaScript allows you to dynamically add properties, just as you did with `a.abc = function`.

Comment: @Bond   I can do `r={}`  then in the console `r.rrr<ENTER>` it says undefined.. but r.rrr(); gives error that function isn't defined.  The function in the snippet says `a.abc.eval.call`  so eval is a method since call is invoked on it.. i'll try changing eval to something else and see what happens.. but it's not dynamically adding a property or even a method in that statement.. i don't think... yeah you're right changing eval to anything and it still works, though I don't see why.. given that a.abc.eval()  doesn't work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86947/discussion-between-barlop-and-bond).